# Pandas Multiuser Time Interpolation

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a dataframe set that looks like the following:

```
time  user value
0     R    3
1     S    5
2     J    6
```

I want to use pandas to synchronize the time for each user such that I end up with a dataframe that looks like this:

```
time  user value
0     R    3
0     S    5
0     J    6
1     S    5
1     R    3
1     J    6
2     J    6
2     R    3
2     S    5
```

In other words I want to use pandas to synchronize the timeseries for each user given that particular users previous value. If there is no previous value it simply back fills the users first value. So e.g. J doesn't show up till 2, so at time 0 and 1 we store J as 6. I'm new to pandas but excited to do this, I had read about align, interpolation, etc, but I didn't see something that focused on multiuser data like this. Would appreciate how to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try first [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) from column `user` and then [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) with custom function `f`, which use [`reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html), [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.sort_values.html), [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.fillna.html) and [`combine_first`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.combine_first.html). Last you can [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) and reorder columns:

```
print df
   time user  value
0     0    R      3
1     1    S      5
2     2    J      6

df = df.set_index(['user'])

def f(x):
    #print x
    x = x.reindex(df.index)
    x = x.sort_values('value')
    x['time'] = x['time'].fillna(method='ffill')   
    x['value'] = x['value'].combine_first(df['value'])
    return x

df = df.groupby(level=0, sort=False).apply(f).reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index()
df = df[['time','user','value']]
print df
   time user  value
0     0    R      3
1     0    S      5
2     0    J      6
3     1    S      5
4     1    R      3
5     1    J      6
6     2    J      6
7     2    R      3
8     2    S      5
```

Comment: This solution depends of your data. It works, if data are like in your sample. If not, maybe doest work or work incorrectly.

Comment: @eWizardII  How does it work? Thank you for voting, if you vote my solution.

Comment: it looks like it is working now I just need to speed it up since I have over 6000 rows and about 60 unique users. any ideas?

Comment: Hmmm, it is complicated, but during weekend I try to find faster solution. Thanks for accepting.